# To find the number of shots arranged in a complete pyramid the base of which is a rectangle

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's assume m and n be the number of short in the long and the short side respectively of the base

I want to figure out a equation which gives the number of shots present in the file in terms of m and n.

I tried  doing this by considering the rows in AP.
My answer is 
$$ \frac{n(n+1)(3m-n)}{6} $$

This just a little bit off to the correct answer which is 
$$\frac{n(n+1)(3m-n+1)}{6}$$

Any suggestions on how to reach to the correct answer are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base has $mn$ shots, the next rectangle up has $(m-1)(n-1)$ and so on up to the top "rectangle" which has $(m-n+1)1$.

We sum first the terms involving $m$: $$m(n+(n-1)+\dots+1)=\frac{1}{2}mn(n+1)$$

We now have to subtract $$1(n-1)+2(n-2)+3(n-3)+\dots+(n-1)1$$ We can split that into $$\Big(1+2+\dots+(n-1)\Big)n-\Big(1^2+2^2+\dots+(n-1)^2\Big)$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}(n-1)n^2-\frac{1}{6}(n-1)n(2n-1)=\frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(3n-2n+1)$$ So the final answer is $$\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(3m-n+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

The top layer consists of a single row of $$m-(n-1) =  m-n+1 $$ shot. In the next layer the number is $2(m-n+2)$

And so on
In the lowest layer the number is $n(m-n+n)$

The sum,
$$ S=(m-n+1)+2(m-n+2).......+n(m-n+n) $$

Simplifying by using sum of n terms and n squares we get the desired reasult.